# execute code in $(document).ready() in external javascript file multiple times with different variable values

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I run one external javascript file, which executes code on $(document).ready() event, multiple times, each time with different value of its own local variables?

Since code in the $(document).ready() event is executed when the DOM is fully loaded, following code alerts "bar" twice.

**external_script.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var local_var = global_var;
    alert( local_var );
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<script>global_var = "foo";</script>
<script src="external_script.js"></script>

<script>global_var = "bar";</script>
<script src="external_script.js"></script>
```

Can I achieve that on second calling of the external_script.js it will alert a different value?

Comment: why not store the values of the variable `global_var` in an array?

Comment: You are attempting an ugly side-effect hack using a global variable.  Please, please fix your code to be a function that accepts an argument that you can just call twice with different arguments when the document is ready.

Comment: Just remove `document ready` and it'll work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are attempting an ugly side-effect hack using a global variable. Please, please fix your code to be a function that accepts an argument that you can just call twice with different arguments when the document is ready.

Thanks, that is exactly what I needed. Now my code looks like this:

**external_script.js:**

```
function do_stuff( local_var ) {
    alert( local_var );
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<script src="external_script.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        do_stuff( "foo" );
        do_stuff( "bar" );
    });
</script>
```